# Does simply conforming to an Objective-C protocol do anything?

Tags: objective-c, uikit, protocols

[CocoaPlant](https://github.com/acani/CocoaPlant) defines a protocol [`CPCoreDataTraits`](https://github.com/acani/CocoaPlant/blob/master/CocoaPlant/CPCoreDataTraits.h), analogous to [UITexInputTraits](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html) like so:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@protocol CPCoreDataTraits <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

@optional

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@end
```

If I only want to synthesize the `managedObjectContext` property for one of my view controllers,

```
@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
@end
```

i.e., I don't want to synthesize the `fetchedResultsController` property or implement any of the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods, should I still conform to the `CPCoreDataTraits` protocol, like so?

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <CPCoreDataTraits>
@end
```

I.e., as long as I don't synthesize the `fetchedResultsController` property or implement any of the `NSFetechedResultsControllerDelegate` methods, then will the end result be exactly as if I had just declared the `managedObjectContext` property normally, like so?

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@end
```

Comment: It enables auto-completion of methods when declaring/defining delegate methods in Xcode!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the protocol declaration, the implementation by your class of the two properties is optional because these two properties have been declared under the @optional statement.
This means that any other class that will use any object conforming to this protocol, must check the effective implementation of an optional method or property before using it.

In the example, any class that wants to access the fetchedResultsController property has to check for the existence of the getter and/or setter methods, e.g. using the:

```
[myController respondsToSelector:@selector(fetchedResultsController)];
[myController respondsToSelector:@selector(setFetchedResultsController:)];
```

If the calling method doesn't do this preliminary check and your protocol implementation doesn't support any of these methods (because optional) then the app will raise an exception.
So your approach is correct, the only difference in the two examples is that if you don't use the  notation than any call to conformsToProtocol: on your object will return NO.